# Есть ли возможность сериализации классов с циклическими зависимостями

Tags: .net, сериализация

Подскажите, есть ли возможность сериализации классов с циклическими зависимостями.Пример,когда 2 класса ссылаются друг на друга

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {


        Person p = new();
        AA a=new AA();
        a.q = p;
        p.w = a;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("q.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        JsonSerializer.Serialize(fs, p);
        fs.Close();
        }
    }
class Person
    {
    public AA w { get; set; }
    }
class AA {
    public Person q{ get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: всегда можно написать свой сериализатор

Comment: Всегда указывайте формат, в который сериализуете. И сериализатор. И язык программирования, кстати. / Почему такие дебильные названия? `AA`, `w`, `g` - что они значат?

Comment: Судя по сигнатуре, это `System.Text.Json`. Добавьте параметр `new JsonSerializerOptions { ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve }`. [How to preserve references and handle or ignore circular references in System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-7-0)